# C3 simplesem and function parameters

Tags: assembly

I am trying to understand how parameters work with C3 simplesem:

Say we have a simple C-like function:

```
 f(int x):
      int y = 10 * x;
      return y
```

As I understand it, the simplesem code would look something similar to (say we are starting at address 100):

```
100     set 2, ?
101     set 3, D[2] * 10
102     set D[0] - 1, D[3]
103     set 1, D[0] - 1
104     set 0, D[D[0] + 1]
105     jump D[D[1]] + 1
```

I am unsure of what line 100 should be, so far as setting the space in D[2] (which I would assume is the local parameter). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is C3 simplesem?